# How to change specific value of a dictionary with multiple values (tuple) without getting TypeError

Tags: python, dictionary, set, tuples

I have a function below which searches for a dictionary key match using an inputted function parameter. If a key match is found I want the value at index 1 (the team) to change to the desired team inputted when the function is called:

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ('Argentina','Barcelona'), 'Ronaldo' : ('Portugal','Juventus'), 'Robben': ('Netherlands','Bayern')}

def setNewTeam(plyr, newTeam):
        for x in dict1:
            if plyr == x:
                dict1[plyr][1] = newTeam

setNewTeam('Messi', 'Manchester')
```

When I run this code however, I get:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I know this must be because tuples are not mutable but there must be a way of making this work since i'm working with dictionaries, can anyone lend a hand here?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `dict1[plyr][1] = newTeam` create a new `tuple` object and place it as value for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you cannot assign new items to tuples because tuples are immutable objects in python.

```
my_tup = (1,2,3)
my_tup[0] = 2 # TypeError
```

What you could do is using a list instead:

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ['Argentina','Barcelona'], 'Ronaldo' : ['Portugal','Juventus'], 'Robben': ['Netherlands','Bayern']}

def setNewTeam(plyr, newTeam):
    for x in dict1:
        if plyr == x:
            dict1[plyr][1] = newTeam

setNewTeam('Messi', 'Manchester')
```

Note how lists are created using `[]` while tuples use `()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ('Argentina','Barcelona'), 'Ronaldo' : ('Portugal','Juventus'), 'Robben': ('Netherlands','Bayern')}

def setNewTeam(plyr, newTeam):
        for x in dict1:
            if plyr == x:
                dict1[plyr] = (dict1[plyr][0], newTeam)

setNewTeam('Messi', 'Manchester')
```

Comment: This seemed to work, can you explain the logic of why this works and not my method? thanks so much

Comment: @CosmicCat Because you are trying to mutate the existing `tuple` object where as in this solution a **separate** `tuple` object is created and assign the corresponding key.

Comment: @CosmicCat: what he said! Here we are not replacing `'Barcelona'` with `'Manchester'` because tuples can be seen as fixed objects. We are reading `'Argentina'` via `dict1[plyr][0]`, then we create a new tuple `('Argentina', 'Manchester')` using this expression `(dict1[plyr][0], newTeam)`, then we overwrite the previous `('Argentina', 'Barcelona')` with the new tuple by writing `dict1[plyr] = (dict1[plyr][0], newTeam)`. Hopefully that's clear :)

Comment: @Guimoute This worked on this specific! When I ran it on a really large dictionary though for a personal project im working on, I got an error saying 'RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration'. I know that this is off topic but is there an easy fix for that also?

Comment: No clue! My first guess would be to iterate over a copy of the dictionnary and modifying the original dictionnary. Usually it is not advise to modify something you're iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to update values, tuple is not the good data-structure. You should use a list.
If you still want to use a tuple, you can build a brand new tuple with :
`dict1[plyr] = (dict1[plyr][0], newTeam)`

Answer (score 0):

`dict1[plyr][1] = newTeam`

Tuples are immutable, but lists are not. You can do something like:

```
list1 = list(dict1[plyr])
list1[1] = newTeam
dict1[plyr] = tuple(list1)
```

It will add the `newTeam` to your desired location, and it will still be a tuple.

Comment: still getting the same result, it stays a tuple with no changes made

Comment: @MaJoR: with `list(dict1[plyr])[1] = newTeam` yes you create a new list equal to `['Argentina', 'Manchester']` but you cannot retrieve it! Your list is not assigned to any variable.

Comment: I am really sorry. I forgot to add it to the `dict`. Thanks for pointing it out. I modified the code a bit. Hope it helps.